# exception handling in int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

i have a code

```html
<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway 
   auto-startup="true"
   native-query="update Transactions t set t.transaction_Status =   :transactionStatus 
   where t.bank_Reference_Number = :bankReferenceNumber "
   entity-manager="entityManager" persist-mode="PERSIST"
   use-payload-as-parameter-source="false">
   <int-jpa:transactional />
   <int-jpa:parameter name="transactionStatus"   expression="payload['transactionStatus']" />
   <int-jpa:parameter name="bankReferenceNumber"  expression="payload['bankReferenceNumber']" />

</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>
```

i want to add error channel , so that if some exception occurs i can see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error-channel` is for flows which works independently of the user: Message Driven Channel Adapter, e.g. `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`, where an Listener Container is started in the infinite loop and does its work actively.

Another sample is Polling Consumer, which runs the polling task periodically, e.g. `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`, or anyone as a consumer on the `QueueChannel`. And again: it does that actively, independently of your existence.

The `<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>` is passive component, therefore it can't do anything until you send a message. Therefore any error caused in this kind of components are thrown to the caller, like it is done in the raw Java method invocation.

Read more about error handling in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler).

For your use-case you should consider to add `error-channel` in the upstream poller if that.

Another case is [ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice), which with its `failureChannel` may play some kind of error handling for the particular `MessageHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

The error channel goes on some upstream component (usually whatever starts the flow).

An alternative is to add and `ExpressionEvaluatingAdvice` to the gateway; see [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice).