# Spring integration kafka how to handle error when produce to kafka

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka

While using int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter to produce to kafka, there seems no error-channel available. In this case how to handle message failed to produce to kafka after reties times?

Any error that could cause produce to kafka failure.
(Following code just code snippet from internet, just wondering how to add error handle to it)

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    topic="test">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext" producer-properties="producerProps">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="XXXXXX:6667"
                   key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   topic="rating"
                   value-serializer="kafkaSerializer"
                   key-serializer="kafkaSerializer"
                   compression-type="none"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>


<util:properties id="producerProps">
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.ms">500</prop>
    <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.messages">10000</prop>
    <prop key="retry.backoff.ms">100</prop>
    <prop key="message.send.max.retries">2</prop>
    <prop key="send.buffer.bytes">5242880</prop>
    <prop key="socket.request.max.bytes">104857600</prop>
    <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="socket.send.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow answers to this question [exception handling in int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915579/exception-handling-in-int-jpaupdating-outbound-gateway).

Since you have there `<polled>`, you can specify `error-channel` and handle errors in the flow on that channel.